# Which validator should be used to implement login in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, validation

Currently, my login form looks like this,

```
class LoginForm extends BaseFormPropel
{
  public function setup()
  {
    $this->setWidgets(array(
      'login_id' => new sfWidgetFormInput(), 
      'pwd' => new sfWidgetFormInputPassword() 
    ));

    $this->widgetSchema->setLabels(array(
        'login_id'=>'Login Id',
        'pwd'=>'Password'
    ));

    $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('member[%s]');

    $this->setValidators(array(
      'login_id' => new sfValidatorPropelChoice(array('model' => 'Member', 'column' => 'login_id', 'required' => true)), 
      'pwd' => new sfValidatorPropelChoice(array('model' => 'Member', 'column' => 'pwd', 'required' => true))
    ));

    $this->errorSchema = new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this->validatorSchema);

    parent::setup();
  }


  public function getModelName()
  {
    return 'Member';
  }

}
```

But this is a wrong implementation, because sfValidatorPropelChoice only ensures the user enters a value that does exist in the column. This means if the database contains the following rows,

login_id | pwd
john, 12345
peter, 67890

A user using john and 67890 to login will succeed.
My question is that, which validator should I use to correct the problem?

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies.
Both solution should work, it's hard to tell which one is better.
May I should just choose the approach used by sfGuard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no nice way to do this job. In sfGuard form validates incoming data and after use form data to sign in user, here is sample

> if ($this->form->isValid()) {
>   $values = $this->form->getValues();
>   $this->getUser()->signin($values['user']);
>   }

I don't know maybe [1](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_2/en/B-Validators#chapter_b_sub_sfvalidatorand) **sfValidatorAnd** do something like that, but login proccess very importand thing in web application so, you should handle with your code this proccess.

http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_2/en/B-Validators#chapter_b_sub_sfvalidatorand

Answer (score 1):

You should use your own post-validator, because you are trying to validate 2 form fields at once. Or you could use [`sfGuardPlugin`](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin) and forget this question.